# Issue with OnSensorChanged() method

Tags: android, sensors

I am having a requirement, when the sensor values changed, need to display some data accordingly.

Currently what I am doing is , if there is a change of 10 degrees for the current azimuth value and previous azimuth value, then perform some action.

The problem is, for every 10 degrees change(as I mentioned in the code) , action is being performed. I don't want this action to be performed for every 10 degrees change. whenever the device is stopped rotating, then the azimuth value is to be considered and the action is to be performed. I have used counter also. But no use. This is killing me.

Here is my code,

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent paramAnonymousSensorEvent) {

        CameraSearch.this.azimuth = paramAnonymousSensorEvent.values[0];

        CountDownTimer myCountDown = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // update the UI with the new count
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d("","Counter finished");
                if (Math.abs(CameraSearch.this.azimuth - previousAzimuth) >= 10) {

                    Log.d("", "Azimuth: " + CameraSearch.this.azimuth
                            + "PreviousAzimuth: " + previousAzimuth);
                    CameraSearch.this.findScreenOrientation();
                    previousAzimuth = CameraSearch.this.azimuth;
                }
            }
        };
        // start the countDown
        myCountDown.start();

    }
};
```

Please suggest me the solution. When the user stops rotating the device, then the current azimuth value is to be taken and perform the action. Please help me out!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to achieve what you want to do. What comes to my mind is that you keep track of the standard deviation of the azimuth and trigger your action when it drops below a certain threshold. What you need is an algorithm that tracks the standard deviation as new samples come in without storing them, it is called an online algorithm. You can find an example of it here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods

To determine the threshold I suggest you collect a bit of data and have a look at the typical values you could expect and decide accordingly.

Comment: @chochop,thanks for responding!! This is not clear to me. Is there any other methology, atleast an Idea is enough. I can't go implementing these algorithms, a bit is time factor is to be considered.

Comment: @Mahe as I said, I cannot think of any easier solution. If you're not happy with trying to implement my answer, just wait for another person to answer